# When one select query is made,is there a possibility that the query will take more than one index(either single or composite)

Tags: mysql, indexing

When one select query is made,is there a possibility that the query will take more than one index (either single or composite)?

Comment: What do you mean precisely? You want to know which indexes are used? Have a look at EXPLAIN, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: In MySQL queries can use 1 index per table

Comment: @Rogier EXPLAIN says that there are  all these possible keys and it uses a key. But my question is that can it take more than one index at a time? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Shadow are you sure about that? Can you suggest me any good documentation please.

Comment: @knowledge_seeker Of course he's sure. See the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on How MySQL Optimizes WHERE Clauses says:

> Each table index is queried, and the best index is used unless the optimizer believes that it is more efficient to use a table scan.

There is one slight exception to the above rule, if [index merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-merge-optimization.html) optimisation is used:

> The Index Merge method is used to retrieve rows with several range
>   scans and to merge their results into one. The merge can produce
>   unions, intersections, or unions-of-intersections of its underlying
>   scans. This access method merges index scans from a single table; it
>   does not merge scans across multiple tables.
>
> In EXPLAIN output, the Index Merge method appears as index_merge in
>   the type column. In this case, the key column contains a list of
>   indexes used, and key_len contains a list of the longest key parts for
>   those indexes.

However, if your indexes are well thought through, then multi-column indexes cover about 50% of the index merge uses cases. Index merge is not a complete exception to the 1 index rule, since the separate indexes are treated together as if  a single index in the process.